# Does "With recompile" recompile all the queries in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

So we have quite a large database and a stored procedure which searches through a large number of documents. Depending on the context, it either fetches millions of documents or just one hundred.

Point is, the procedure takes 30 seconds for both millions and hundred documents which is surreal. If I add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` after **each** of the five queries, it takes a second for 100 documents and (expected) 30 seconds for millions of documents.

I've tried creating a procedure with `WITH RECOMPILE` option but it seems that it doesn't recompile queries in it.

Is this correct? Does the `WITH RECOMPILE` on stored procedure recompiles inner queries or just the execution plan for an entire SP? How can I do this without repeating `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` after each query?

Comment: from msdn blog 'OPTION (RECOMPILE) is a statement level command that has some very distinct advantages over WITH RECOMPILE.'

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/ read the part on OPTION (RECOMPILE)

Comment: does it make sense to put OPTION (RECOMPILE) on all the queries that appear to benefit from it?  To my mind evidence has emerged that there might be advantages in doing that over a single issuing of WITH RECOMPILE

Answer (score 8):

> Does the WITH RECOMPILE on stored procedure recompiles inner queries or just the execution plan for an entire SP?

inner queries or just execution plan,i am not sure what does this mean ?  With Recompile at Stored proc level,will cause recompilation every time the proc is executed and query is not saved to Cache

> How can I do this without repeating OPTION (RECOMPILE) after each query?

```
create proc usp_test
with Recompile 
as
Begin
--code
End
```

**Some More Details:**
`With Recompile` will recompile a new plan for the entire stored proc ,everytime its run..

suppose ,you have below proc

```
create proc usp_test
as
Begin
select * from t1
 go
select * from t2
End
```

adding recompile on top of stored proc,will cause SQLServer to recompile all the batches in Stored proc

Instead of recompiling,the total proc,if you know for sure ,which batch is causing issues,you can add Option(Recompile)  like below

```
 create proc usp_test
    as

    Begin

    select * from t1 option(recompile)

    select * from t2

    End
```

doing this,you are avoiding unnecessary recompilation of other batches

Comment: But putting With Recompile on a procedure-level doesn't affect performance. Statement-level recompile does. Why is this happening, especially if WITH RECOMPILE is supposed to recompile an entire execution plan?

Comment: `But putting With Recompile on a procedure-level doesn't affect performance`.Can you elaborate on this

Comment: @TheGameiswar Sure. As I've said, the SP consists of five queries. In different contexts it either loads 1M or 100 records. For 100 records it takes 1-2 seconds with query hint `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` after **each** query, but without it it takes nearly 30 seconds. On the other hand, if I put `WITH RECOMPILE` on stored procedure level it's as if I didn't do anything, it still takes 30 seconds to 1 minute. In other words, it seems that `WITH RECOMPILE` doesn't do the same thing as `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` for each query.

Comment: @skafander1: interesting,in first case,you are capturing single statement query performance,but later you are using with recompile at proc level,how are you calculating single statement performance by saying `WITH RECOMPILE on stored procedure level it's as if I didn't do anything, it still takes 30 seconds to 1 minute`

Comment: it sounds to me that OPTION (RECOMPILE) IS NOT the same thing as WITH RECOMPILE - read the link I put in a comment to you - it sounds like you have encountered one of the 'distinct advantages'

Comment: @Cato:Both are not same,one does statement level recompilation,other does at proc level

Comment: @JOHN Actually I agree with the questioner that the answer is missing the point somewhat

Comment: @TheGameiswar  plus supposed other advantages with OPTION (RECOMPILE) - so no it will not be the same to put WITH RECOMPILE on the stored procedure as putting OPTION (RECOMPILE) on each query - the latter is said to be better - that's explain his better performance with that approach

Comment: @Cato: option(recompile) is good for performance for sure,since it recompiles only what we asked for ,I don't think,like adding option(recompile) to every batch is better than with recompile at proc level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130532/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-cato).

Answer (score 2):

Both OPTION(RECOMPILE) and WITH RECOMPILE will give you execution plans based on the parameters used each time, but only OPTION (RECOMPILE) allows "parameter embedding optimization" where the parameters are replaced with literal constants when its parsing the queries. This can allow the optimizer to make simplifications to the query.

I would find out which query is actually causing the performance issue and use OPTION(RECOMPILE) on that.

Comment: he seems to have problems with all the queries, which is only fixed by putting OPTION (RECOMPILE)  on all the queries - I think his question is to ask why a single instance of WITH RECOMPILE gives inferior results - various MSDN blogs seem to say OPTION (RECOMPILE) has some advantages.